# How to develop a logic to read data from .prn file in java....?

Tags: java

How to view these .prn files & after that how to read data from them by using java..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PRN is byte stream that is sent to printer for Printing. 
You can use [Java Print Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/index.html) for that.

You need to copy it using Dos Prompt.

If you ask user about printer selection using `PrinterJob`

```
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.printDialog();
```

Comment: can you plz share a littile bit more bcoz i have no idea about this...thanks for replying

Comment: what you really want to achieve? Do you want to print using Java or do you want to print using PRN?

Comment: I don't know whether converting it back is possible in java or not. The only way is get to know about PRN more and then parse it for each format like PDF, XCEL etc.